# Does different meta tags on server and client matter? React SSR

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, meta-tags, react-helmet

I'm using React in combination with Express for SSR-rendering. When doing for example, a CURL request on my local site I get the server content with unset meta-tags.
But when I visit the page through a browser and React running in the browser, the meta tags are all good since they're from another "head"-component.

My question is how much does this matter? Both from a SEO-view and general practice. Should I always make sure that the html is identical on both server and client render?

Comment: Most crawlers run a lot of JS nowadays, so you're likely good the way it is.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've heard this as well. 
But I'm still in doubt if it's correct to have different HTML on server and client. It does seem like this isn't uncommon in other projects though.